# infinite set of constraints involving vector norms

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, optimization, vector-spaces, linear-programming

Suppose that we are given $$\overline{a} \in \mathbb{R}^2$$ and let $$D=\{u \in \mathbb{R}^2 : ||u||_1 \leq 1 \}$$ Let $\beta$ be some fixed constant and consider $$a^Tx \leq \beta, (a-\overline{a} \in D)$$
Then the above is an infinite intersection of hyperplanes. I want to rewrite the above constraints into a single constraint, I am given the hint that I should write the new constraint involving the infinite norm, but I do not see a clear clue on how to rewrite the constraints.

$$||x||_1 = \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|$$
$$||x||_{\infty} = \max\{ |x_j|: j =1,...,n\}$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "The above is an infinite intersection of hyperplanes"?

Comment: "Halfplanes", not "hyperplanes". You are in $\Bbb R^2$, so its "hyperplanes" are just called "lines". And for a fixed $a$, the inequality $a^Tx \le \beta$ describes a closed half-plane bounded by the line $a^Tx = \beta$. But it is not clear to me what you mean by $\overline a$ here.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your constraint as

$$
(a - \bar{a})^T x \leq \beta - \bar{a}^T x, \quad \forall (a - \bar{a}) \in D \Leftrightarrow
\sup_{v \in D} v^T x \leq \beta - \bar{a}^T x.
$$

The left-hand-side is just
$$
\sup_{v: \|v\|_1 \leq 1} v^T x = \| x \|_{\infty}.
$$